# python spliting of string only first element accessable

Tags: python, split

I've googled around a bit and it seems like nobody has had this problem before so here we go:

Function:

```
def split_time(time_string):
time = time_string.split('T')
time_array = time[-1]
return time_array
```

Call of Function:

```
class Entry():

  def __init__(self,start,end,summary,description):
   self.start_date = split_time(start)
   self.end_date = split_time(end)
   self.summary = summary
   self.description = description
```

My function recieves a string containing a date time format like this: `2018-03-17T09:00:00+01:00`
I want to cut it at 'T' so i used `time = time_string.split('T')` which worked just fine!

The output of time is `['2018-05-08', '12:00:00+02:00']`.

So now i wanted to split it some more and ran into the following error:
While i can access `time[0]` which delivers the output `2018-05-08` i cant access `time[1]`, i just get an Index out of range Error.

To me it seems like time does contain an array with two strings inside because of its output yo i'm really at a loss right now.

Any help would be appreciated  =)

(and an explanation too!)

Comment: Can you please post the results of `time[-1]`?

Comment: it is 12:00:00+02:00 ! 
I never thought of using a negativ index... is split always filling up in the negative direction?

Comment: Hmm.. No split returns a regular list. `time[1]` should have returned the time, and not an error. If you edit your question to include all of your code, I might be able to better point out what went wrong :)

Comment: I edited it - but its a bit hard to post everything because i'm getting the string i give to the function from google calendar
But to be honest i dont think it has anything to do with that because its a regular string :b

Anyway thanks for the [-1] idea ;D

Comment: We don't need to see your Google Calendar code, but we _do_ need to see the strings you're feeding to the code you posted so we can try to reproduce this bug.

Comment: the string is '2018-05-08T12:00:00+02:00'

Comment: @SallyZeitler Glad it works for you! I posted it as an answer for others who come along. Please accept it if you think it's appropriate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `item[-1]` to access the last item in the last.

Still unsure why `item[1]` would throw an error for a list with two items in it.